# CocoaPods spec lint raises errors

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I've created an iOS framework project and added a .podspec to it. The framework is generated fine as well as the included demo project.
But I'm getting errors during the pod spec lint test.

The podspec file I'm using is

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|s.name         = "HorizontalPicker"
s.version      = "1.0.0"
s.summary      = "A similar to UIPickerView but horizontal picker view."
s.homepage     = "https://github.com/HHuckebein/HorizontalPicker"
s.license      = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE.txt' }
s.author       = { "RABE_IT Services" => "info@berndrabe.de" }
s.source       = { :git => "https://github.com/HHuckebein/HorizontalPicker.git", :tag => "1.0.0" }
s.platform     = :ios, '5.1'
s.source_files = 'HorizontalPicker/*.{h,m}'
s.framework    = 'QuartzCore'
s.requires_arc = true
end


-> HorizontalPicker (1.0.0)
- ERROR | [xcodebuild]  HorizontalPicker/HorizontalPicker/HPickerView.m:42:30: error: unknown type name 'CAShapeLayer'
- ERROR | [xcodebuild]  HorizontalPicker/HorizontalPicker/HPickerView.m:42:1: error: property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type
- ERROR | [xcodebuild]  HorizontalPicker/HorizontalPicker/HPickerView.m:63:16: error: property 'masksToBounds' cannot be found in forward class object 'CALayer'
- NOTE  | [xcodebuild]  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:82:75: note: forward declaration of class here
- ERROR | [xcodebuild]  HorizontalPicker/HorizontalPicker/HPickerView.m:112:32: error: member reference base type 'int *' is not a structure or union
- ERROR | [xcodebuild]  HorizontalPicker/HorizontalPicker/HPickerView.m:319:21: error: property 'borderColor' cannot be found in forward class object 'CALayer'
- ERROR | [xcodebuild]  HorizontalPicker/HorizontalPicker/HPickerView.m:320:21: error: property 'borderWidth' cannot be found in forward class object 'CALayer'
- ERROR | [xcodebuild]  HorizontalPicker/HorizontalPicker/HPickerView.m:340:33: error: property 'borderWidth' cannot be found in forward class object 'CALayer'
- ERROR | [xcodebuild]  HorizontalPicker/HorizontalPicker/HPickerView.m:341:33: error: property 'borderColor' cannot be found in forward class object 'CALayer'
- ERROR | [xcodebuild]  HorizontalPicker/HorizontalPicker/HPickerView.m:401:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'CAGradientLayer'
- ERROR | [xcodebuild]  HorizontalPicker/HorizontalPicker/HPickerView.m:410:3: error: unknown type name 'CAGradientLayer'; did you mean 'CGGradientRef'?
- NOTE  | [xcodebuild]  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGGradient.h:8:28: note: 'CGGradientRef' declared here
- ERROR | [xcodebuild]  HorizontalPicker/HorizontalPicker/HPickerView.m:410:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'CAGradientLayer'; did you mean 'gradientLayer'?
- NOTE  | [xcodebuild]  HorizontalPicker/HorizontalPicker/HPickerView.m:410:20: note: 'gradientLayer' declared here
- ERROR | [xcodebuild]  HorizontalPicker/HorizontalPicker/HPickerView.m:410:54: error: expected expression
- ERROR | [xcodebuild]  HorizontalPicker/HorizontalPicker/HPickerView.m:411:16: error: member reference base type 'CGGradientRef *' (aka 'struct CGGradient **') is not a structure or union
- ERROR | [xcodebuild]  HorizontalPicker/HorizontalPicker/HPickerView.m:412:16: error: member reference base type 'CGGradientRef *' (aka 'struct CGGradient **') is not a structure or union
- ERROR | [xcodebuild]  HorizontalPicker/HorizontalPicker/HPickerView.m:414:22: error: member reference base type 'CGGradientRef *' (aka 'struct CGGradient **') is not a structure or union
- ERROR | [xcodebuild]  HorizontalPicker/HorizontalPicker/HPickerView.m:416:22: error: member reference base type 'CGGradientRef *' (aka 'struct CGGradient **') is not a structure or union
- ERROR | [xcodebuild]  HorizontalPicker/HorizontalPicker/HPickerView.m:436:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'CAGradientLayer'; did you mean 'gradientLayer'?
- ERROR | [xcodebuild]  HorizontalPicker/HorizontalPicker/HPickerView.m:436:10: error: reference to local variable 'gradientLayer' declared in enclosing context
- ERROR | [xcodebuild]  HorizontalPicker/HorizontalPicker/HPickerView.m:436:10: error: bad receiver type 'CGGradientRef *' (aka 'struct CGGradient **')
- ERROR | [xcodebuild]  fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
```

Analyzed 1 podspec.

[!] The spec did not pass validation.

EDIT
The directory structure is like so.
/HorizontalPicker/HorizontalPicker.podspec
/HorizontalPicker/HorizontalPicker/Source Code lives here

Comment: is there an import missing? do you have a test project where you are compiling this library when developing?

Comment: NO and YES. Both, the demo project and the framework work fine.

Comment: Well - at least it seems that QuartzCore is missing here when running lint, but it is included in the project

Comment: fair enough. I've not seen this error with cocoapods but I was thinking if the QuartzCore import was in the project's pch file it would be missing when podspec analyses it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To see what happened I used

```
pod spec lint --no-clean ...
```

which leaves the generated test pod inside /tmp. So I found QuartzCore was added in the pch file, which is ok for a normal project, but not in the class files.

So it was not the best coding style.

Answer (score 5):

In my case lint was testing the spec against OS X SDK instead of the iOS SDK.

Both platforms have the Security framework but the APIs are not the same, thus the errors.

Just adding `s.platform = :ios` to the podspec fixed it.

Comment: This whole damn thing is insane, by your answer did the trick for me as well. Thanks!